# How to place a div inside another div already rendered in html

Tags: html

I haven't found a good example or solution for this due to the nature of my question.

Background:
I am building a wedding website that only allows me to use their templates (www.mywedding.com). It is a pretty good website and so far I think they have done a good job of allowing users to make a fairly customized site.  The issue is, my fiance and I are more creative than others. I have been able to insert some HTML tags like `<img>` and `<a href>` so that I could put links and more images than they allow but now my fiance wants me to put our trademark initials at the top of every page.

What I am trying to do:
The existing structure

```
<body>
    <div id="t-container">
        <div id="t-header">
            <h1><span></span></h1>
            <h2><span></span></h2>
            <div id="t_header_image">
                <img src="thesource" />
            </div>
            <!-- This is where I want to place my content -->
        <div id="t-header">
        <div id="t-center">
            <div id="t-links">
                <!-- The navigation links on left side -->
            </div>
           <div id="t-content">
                <!-- The content from their templates -->
                <div id="myImage">
                    <!-- This is the content I want up top -->
                    <img src="mySource" />
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

What I want to do is move my image (div or no div) into the header section.  Thier site is written in PHP and my UI knoweldge is very limited. I am not sure if I can inject css or use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just adding CSS into your img tag and see if their template allows it:

```
<img src="mySource" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0" />
```

That should place your image on the upper right corner of the page. Just fiddle with the `top` and `right` values to get what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to get the top and right from the existing div image and then use that for my style? When I use the code you recommended the image ended up at the top-right of the "t-center" div

Comment: It sounds like t-center has "position:relative". If you can override that CSS, you would be golden. Have you tried adding a `<style>` tag?

Comment: Looking at thier style using firebug I notice that the position is relative. I updated it and did `<img src="mySource" style="position:absolure; top:-150px; right:0px" />` and it placed my image into the location that I was looking for. I was just hoping that there was a way to grab it from their div's position. I would "vote up" your answer, but no rep means no voting ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, getting the position of a div cannot be done without some scripting, I think. And no problem with the voting, just glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use javascript, then `innerHTML` would do what you need.

```
document.getElementById('t-header').innerHTML+='<your html="stuff">';
```

Comment: I can only place text within their template fields and it scrubs for <script> (which is a good thing)